# How to keep at least one panel in an accordion expanded?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Say I have an accordion which has 2 expansion panels, by default, there are three states of this accordion:

State 1: Panel 1 closed, Panel 2 closed

State 2: Panel 1 expanded, Panel 2 closed

State 3: Panel 1 closed, Panel 2 expanded

I want to forbid user from closing all panels. They can open panel 1 close panel 2, or open panel 2 close panel 1, but not close them both.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear as it is. It's an accordion. By default, it can have at most one open panel, but it can have all the panels closed. OP wants to prevent this, so that, at all times, one and only one panel is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open and closed events that is provided by mat-expansion panel
check this answer here: 
[how to close a mat-accordion when other mat-accordion is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028796/how-to-close-a-mat-accordion-when-other-mat-accordion-is-opened)

Comment: say this is the one panel expanded in an accordion, I can still click on this panel and make it collapsed, then I have all panels collapsed. What I want is to get rid of the possibility of collapse all panels

Comment: the other panels should have their own <mat-expansion-panel>. Are you saying they all expand together?

Comment: I want to prevent user from closing all panels in an accordion. If there are 3 panels in an accordion, they can be (open, close, close),(close, open, close),(close, close, open), but not (close, close, close)

Comment: oh you mean close the others while one is open? I updated my answer

Comment: That's not what the question means at all. It means, how to prevent the user from closing all the panels in an accordion. The accordion is the key part. It already closes the other panels by itself when the user opens one of them. What is needed is to prevent the user from closing the open one...